# Where to use Celery in Django?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm reading [this tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) of Django Celery and I'm wondering since Django is a web development framework, where Celery will be actually used to queue the tasks in web development ?

Give your suggestions using examples .

Comment: Any long-running work that wouldn't be possible to do in the web request.

Comment: @SimeonVisser - Like what? Please provide any real-life example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, anything that doesn't *have* to happen in the typical request-response web application cycle.

The goal is generally to improve performance by doing those tasks in the background.

A few examples:

- Sending notification emails.
- Updating or invalidating non-critical caches
- Calling an external web service

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Lets say if I'm requesting something `a`, `b` and `c` from a web page and processing these variables takes a long time. Separate function are taking care of processing each variable. So, normally I would do, `a = a_funct()`  `b = b_funct()` and `c = c_funct()`. Instead of this I should use celery on these functions , so that I dont have to wait for `a's` response to go on b and then on c, instead all the functions should run asynchronously. Am I correct?

Comment: Secondly, how can I use celery on `Updating or invalidating non-critical caches`?

Comment: @prafulbagai That's not the use case for celery. You use Celery when requesting your page triggers an action that is not needed in the response but has to happen at some point. Here's an example: an user subscribes to your mailing list. You don't need to send them a welcome email before you can return a response: "OK, you're subscribed". So what you do i you create an asynchronous task in Celery to send the email, and return "OK you're subscribed". The user receives the HTTP response now, and will receive the email later, when Celery processes the task.